# Problem with probability and dependent events

Tags: probability

$a$,$b$ and $c$ are three different random number from a uniform distribution $U(0,N)$ (suppose if you want $N \rightarrow +\infty $ but actually it will be something like 100 or 1000 or 10000).

$a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$

**Question:** What is the probability that
 $a \geq b \wedge a \geq c$
?

Well. The probabilities I know are

$P(a \geq b) \simeq 0.5$

$P(a \geq c) \simeq 0.5$

$P(b \geq c) \simeq 0.5$

From transitional property of $\geq$ I also know that

$a \geq b \wedge b \geq c \implies a \geq c$

then they are not independent events.

Using an exhaustive simulation I know the result being $ \simeq 0.333$, however I'd like to calculate this result analytically from hypothesis in order to generalize the calculation in the case of more than three variables ($a,b,c,d,...$).
For example the next step will be to calculate the probability of having

$a \geq b \wedge a \geq c \wedge a \geq d$

and so on.

Edit: Is it correct to simply assume that this probability is $1 \over V$, with $V$ being the number of random variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are independent and uniformly distributed on the set $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$, then $P(b\leqslant k,c\leqslant k)=(k/N)^2$ for every $k$ in  $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ hence $$P(b\leqslant a,c\leqslant a)=\frac1{N^2}E(a^2).
$$
Now,
$$
E(a^2)=\frac1N\sum_{k=1}^Nk^2=\frac16(N+1)(2N+1),
$$
hence
$$
P(b\leqslant a,c\leqslant a)=\frac{(N+1)(2N+1)}{6N^2}=\frac13+\frac{3N+1}{6N^2}.
$$
The formula on the RHS shows that the limit when $N\to\infty$ is $\frac13$, which is, by symmetry, the corresponding probability when the common distribution is continuous, that is, when there is no tie, almost surely.

Comment: very good answer, thanks. Then with more than three variables and N sufficiently big is it correct to assume the probabilit of having $a \geq others$ equal to $1 \over V$ ?

Comment: "Equal to" this value? No. *Converging to* it when $N\to\infty$, yes (with an error term of order $1/N$).

Comment: ok, good, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are chosen uniformly at random from a distribution, then the probability that $a$ is largest is the same as the probability that $b$ is the largest or that $c$ is the largest. Since in every case there is a largest number, the probability should be $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: For example, when $N=2$, the result is $\frac58\ne\frac13$.

Comment: "When I say N=2", I mean N=2. Note that a, b and c are integer random variables.

Comment: Nevermind that last comment. But he says that $N \to + \infty$.

Comment: Sure, and the probability is *never* $\frac13$.